# Using residuals to estimate synthetic control weights

Tags: regression, econometrics, synthetic-controls

I would like to estimate weights using the synthetic control method (SCM), in particular using the synthdid package provided by Arkhangelsky et al. (2021) for R. Since I would like to include time-varying covariates, I need to manually regress (say with OLS) the outcome variable on the covariates and then calculate the SCM weights using the residuals (as suggested by the authors) as the package does not allow the inclusion of covariates directly. I have two issues connected to this operation as I have not been able to find answers by myself.

Firstly, the literature is not particularly clear on whether the regression needs to include both the control units and the treated one or just the control units. I also do not fully understand why I need to use pre-treatment observations only and then balance the treatment effects using the OLS weights computed with pre-treatment observations.

Secondly, I cannot figure out why it is often suggested to use time-invariant summaries (e.g. mean) of the covariates in the regression (e.g. Ben-Michael et al.,2021). Why would it be wrong to use a pooled OLS?